# Dash-to-Dock keeps disappearing on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dock

I know there are several seemingly similar questions out there but none really apply to my problem:

I am on a brand new Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME desktop) on a new desktop computer and I have installed GNOME Tweaks and the Dash to Dock GNOME extension with default settings. It works just fine after installing it for a while but at some point the dock just disappears.

When I go to [its website](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/), the switch is set to on. If I try to turn it off, it says ERROR.

If I uninstall and reinstall, it works just fine.

Any ideas?

Edit: When I lock the screen and log back in, the dock reappears, too.

Comment: have you overcome it yet?

Comment: I am only occasionally using Ubuntu anymore but it seems like the problem went away through regular updates.

Comment: so that is Ubuntu internal problems? :s I have the same issue with 16.04

Answer (score 1):

I use 16.04, and the way I overcome this is by soft restart. Open command `Alt+F2` then enter `r` and everything backs to normal to me